# pdfbox - pdf increase size after converting to grayscale

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to convert scanned PDF to grayscale PDF. I found 2 solutions for that.

First one is to just use `renderImage`

```java
private void convertToGray() throws IOException {
    File pdfFile = new File(PATH);
    try (PDDocument originalPdf = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
         PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
        LOGGER.info("Current heap after loading file: {}", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(originalPdf);
        for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < originalPdf.getNumberOfPages(); pageNum++) {
//          PDImageXObject pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bufferedImage);
            BufferedImage grayImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNum, 300F, ImageType.GRAY);
            PDImageXObject pdImage = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, grayImage);
            float pageWight = originalPdf.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox().getWidth();
            float pageHeight = originalPdf.getPage(pageNum).getMediaBox().getHeight();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(pageWight, pageHeight));
            doc.addPage(page);
            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page)) {
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0F, 0F, pageWight, pageHeight);
            }
        }
        doc.save(NEW_PATH);
    }
}
```

But this leads to increase size of the file (because some PDFs has less DPI than 300.

Second one is to just replace existing image with gray analog

```java
private void convertByImageToGray() throws IOException {
    File pdfFile = new File(PATH);
    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)) {
        List<COSObject> objects = document.getDocument().getObjectsByType(COSName.IMAGE);
        for (COSObject object : objects) {
            LOGGER.info("Class: {}; {}", object.getClass(), object.toString());
        }
        for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageNum++) {
            PDPage page = document.getPage(pageNum);
            replaceImage(document, page);
        }
        document.save(NEW_PATH);
    }
}

private void replaceImage(PDDocument document, PDPage page) throws IOException {
    PDResources resources = page.getResources();
    Iterable<COSName> xObjectNames = resources.getXObjectNames();
    if (xObjectNames != null) {
        for (COSName xObjectName : xObjectNames) {
            PDXObject object = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
            if (object instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject img1 = (PDImageXObject) object;
                BufferedImage bufferedImage1 = img1.getImage();
                BufferedImage grayBufferedImage = convertBufferedImageToGray(bufferedImage1);
//                    PDImageXObject grayImage = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, grayBufferedImage);
                PDImageXObject grayImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, grayBufferedImage);
                resources.put(xObjectName, grayImage);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static BufferedImage convertBufferedImageToGray(BufferedImage sourceImg) {
    ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
    ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(sourceImg.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), cs, null);
    op.filter(sourceImg, sourceImg);
    return sourceImg;
}
```

But still some files increase in size like 3 times (even they were already grayscale; interesting that int this case [`JPEGFactory`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/JPEGFactory.html) produces larger files than [`LosslessFactory`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/LosslessFactory.html)). All images in grayscale PDF have the same size as original ones. And I don't understand why.

Maybe there is a better way to make grayscale PDF with predictable size (except ghostscript)?

**UPDATE:** I've just realized that the issue is with creating PDF from image. It does not compress as well.

For example, I have dummy 1-page scan file that is less than 1 Mb. But if I get image from it (directly copying via Acrobat Reader to Paint, or via code above) it size is ~8-10 Mb depending on the method. And if I create new PDF from this image it's barely compressed. Here is example code:

```java
File pdfFile = new File(FULL_FILE);
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)) {
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("example.png", document);
    try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
        contents.drawImage(pdImage, 0F, 0F);
    }
    document.save(FULL_FILE_NEW);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes LosslessFactory produces smaller files compared to JPEGFactory

In the below link there are different methods to try and achieve the same goal. Overall the best quality gray scale image was the one from Option 6, however this was by no means the fastest (I myself used Option 4). Comparisons are also provided for you to choose

[This](http://codehustler.org/blog/java-to-create-grayscale-images-icons/) link contains possible ways to convert color images to black. It helped me a lot.
Let me know if it works for you and approve my answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks for reply. I've already seen this article. It was great help. But the issue is not in the way I make image grayscale. But in creating/updating PDF itself. I guess I need to look onto compression

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25345330)

Comment: @LukasKörfer I totally agree with you but as the link contains 6 options i didn't wanted to type everything. Still I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to copy the whole article (which is understandable), consider at least adding a *summary* of the options.

Comment: @mkl I have updated my answer by referring to the conclusion provided in the link. Thanks for suggestion.